# Change Eclipse sidebar vertical scope highlighting

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, scope, highlight, sidebar

I just installed Ubuntu after using Eclipse on Windows 8 for some time.  The only thing I can't figure out how to modify is the color of the vertical bar when you're working under a current class or method in a file.

Example: in Windows the default was this lovely blue as shown below:

[image]

But in Ubuntu this is orange in color (as shown below) which distracts me:

[image]

Any idea on how I can fix this?
Not sure why the colors are different? My Eclipse on Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04 are both Kepler 4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called as Range indicator.You can switch off the range indicator.

#### How:

Click `Windows > Preferences`. Navigate to `General > Editors > Text Editors`. De select `Show Range indicator` option.

#### How to change the color:

Color of range indicator is controlled by OS not by eclipse.

- Install `gtk-theme-config` tool from Ubuntu software centre. Change the `Highlight background color`. Logout and login again.

[image]

- You can also do this by installing dconf-editor as [said here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/09/how-to-change-nautilus-background-color-in-ubuntu-13-04/)

After change:

[image]

Note that this will change the selection colour in other applications also like nautilus, Firefox etc.

#### How to apply this only to eclipse:

Somewhere on your home directory, create a gtkrc file (like: ~/.gtkrc-eclipse) with following content:

```css
gtk-color-scheme = "selected_bg_color:#0AFC02\nselected_fg_color:#FFFFFF\norginal_selected_bg_color:#f07746\ntooltip_bg_color:#f5f5c5\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000"

style "range-indicator"
{
    base[SELECTED]    = @selected_bg_color
}
class "GtkWindow" style "range-indicator"
```

---

Launch eclipse from command line like,

> env GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/<Your current theme>/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/<user name>/.gtkrc-eclipse '
>
> env GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/chandrayya/.gtkrc-eclipse '/opt/eclipse-3.3/eclipse'

You can find out your current theme by executing,

> gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme

**Note that is also changes the text selection background and foreground colour in editor, we can't avoid it.**

Comment: thanks a lot; tried to come up with many things it could be called.  will check back for info on how to apply this only to eclipse (& vote your answer up when i have enough "reputation" :) )