# Eclipse matching bracket margin mark - What is it properly called, and how to change its appearance

Tags: css, eclipse

[image]

The question is basically just the title.  In the above image, Eclipse is highlighting the function scope/block with the blue dotted pattern on the left margin.  While helpful, I find the pattern visually distracting, especially using Moonrise or the Dark theme.  What is this feature called, and where would I find its appearance settings/controls?

This is eclipse 4.4 with PyDev and StatET installed, though I see the same behavior with basic Java files as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Linux OS.

> What is this feature called, and where would I find its appearance settings/controls?

This is called as Range indicator.You can switch off the range indicator.

**How**

> Click Windows > Preferences. Navigate to General > Editors > Text Editors. De select Show Range indicator option.

If you want to change the colour then refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25155197/1391924

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  Why the comment about Linux though?  Eclipse is cross-platform, and your answer applied equally well to my windows machine.

Comment: Yes.But eclipse uses the underlying OS's windowing system to create widget like Button,List,Table etc. That's why the same eclipse application looks differently on Linux and on Windows.