# Blue highlighted column next to line numbers in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using CDT (C editor) for Eclipse and noticing an odd blue-highlighted column to the left of line numbers (screenshot below). Any thoughts on how to remove this?

[image]

Comment: It is to show setting breakpoints, and other line-specific information such as error/warning icons.  I don't think you can disable it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change Eclipse sidebar vertical scope highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151476/change-eclipse-sidebar-vertical-scope-highlighting) Also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065076/eclipse-matching-bracket-margin-mark-what-is-it-properly-called-and-how-to-ch/26094102#26094102

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's called "Range Indicator" and it outlines the method (function, procedure) where your cursor is. You can disable it in Window/Preferences/General/Editors/Text Editors/Show Range Indicator