# Change GTK3 tooltip color only for Eclipse running in Ubuntu

Tags: java, css, eclipse, ubuntu, gtk3

I am running Eclipse Mars on Ubuntu 15.04. I have seen instructions to change GTK3 tooltip fg/bg color at system-wide level. My question is how can I change the GTK3 tooltip fg/bg color only for Eclipse without affecting other applications.

(GTK3 and CSS are not my fields of expertise so I really need some help here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to fix Eclipse tooltip color without falling back to GTK2 and without affecting any other application.

The fix is captured in a script and it can be accessed here.

https://github.com/KiranMohan/eclipse-gtk3-ubuntu

The script makes a copy of the Ambiance theme, modifies the tooltip color and then writes a launcher for eclipse with this new Theme.

Comment: You still falling back to GTK2.

Comment: @snoop - This answer was valid for Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04. 
Not anymore.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to apply GTK changes only to eclipse:

Somewhere on your home directory, create a gtkrc file (like: ~/.gtkrc-eclipse) with following content:

```css
gtk-color-scheme = "selected_bg_color:#0AFC02\nselected_fg_color:#FFFFFF\norginal_selected_bg_color:#f07746\ntooltip_bg_color:#f5f5c5\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000"
```

Launch eclipse from command line like,

> env GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/<Your current theme>/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/<user name>/.gtkrc-eclipse '
>
> env GTK2_RC_FILES=/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/chandrayya/.gtkrc-eclipse '/opt/eclipse-3.3/eclipse'

You can find out your current theme by executing,

> gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme

Choose your fg/bg color code.

Also refer this post [Change Eclipse sidebar vertical scope highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151476/change-eclipse-sidebar-vertical-scope-highlighting/25155197#25155197).

Comment: I dont hv my Ubuntu laptop with me right now to check itout. But I hv got a feeling this will not work with GTK3. Anyway I will give it a try later.

Comment: Waiting for your reply

Comment: This configuration is for GTK2. Wont work for Eclipse 4.5 which uses GTK3 by default. Of course, you an force Eclipse to use GTK2.

Comment: The first link "Refer to this post" is not working anymore. Any chance to resurrect the contents?