# Eclipse neon weird behaviour in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, tooltip, gtk3

I have Eclipse neon (4.6) as well as STS 3.8.0 (based on eclipse 4.6) installed in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. All the tooltips are behaving differently as shown in attached screenshot.

[image: tooltip]

Then, I understood that according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45001/how-to-fix-black-tooltips-in-eclipse) and [this](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1069038/), it is a bug with gtk-3.

As mentioned int the given threads, I installed gnome-color-picker and then fixed the tooltip issue. But that changes the tooltips in many other apps which is not much desired.

Then I tried changing the gtk to 2 in eclipse in eclipse.ini file which resulted in missing menu icons and again tooltip issue (this time black background and white text) as shown below.

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```

[image: menus][image: black-tool-tip]

> Is there any permanent fix for this? (other than using gnome-color-picker)
>   Or, when can this issue be fixed in near future in Ubuntu?
>
> P.S : Same issue is noticed in STS-3.8.0 which is based on eclipse
>   4.6(neon)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix for you.

> This fixes Eclipse tooltip color without falling back to GTK2 and without affecting any other application.

The fix is captured in a script and it can be accessed [here](https://github.com/KiranMohan/eclipse-gtk3-ubuntu).

The script makes a copy of the Ambiance theme, modifies the tooltip color and then writes a launcher for eclipse with this new Theme.

See this [Change GTK3 tooltip color only for Eclipse running in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920268/change-gtk3-tooltip-color-only-for-eclipse-running-in-ubuntu/32963994#32963994)

---

Check this [blog](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/11/ubuntu-unity-menu-button-have-icons/) and use method2 to enable menu icons if you choose to use GTK2.

Answer (score 0):

Editing GTK3 theme settings as follows is what worked for me:

```
This command sets background to pale yellow and foreground to black: 

sudo sed -i 's/@define-color tooltip_bg_color.*;/@define-color tooltip_bg_color #ffffda;/g' /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css && sudo sed -i 's/@define-color tooltip_fg_color.*;/@define-color tooltip_fg_color #000000;/g' /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css
```

Source: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=439884#c20