# Change Text Highlight Color in Eclipse Console

Tags: linux, eclipse-mars, ide-customization

## Question

Is it at all possible to change the color of the **text highlight** in Eclipse **console** to something more visible in Manjaro Linux? Your time and help are both much appreciated.

## Important notes

- I am using the default GTK theme. I do not want to use a different theme.
- For testing, I have tried using a different theme, but that didn't help.

## Problem

Currently, I am stuck with a barely visible light grey text selection in Eclipse **console** in the following two scenarios:

1. When manually selecting text
2. When using the `Find\Replace...` search function

### Supporting screenshots

#### Manual mouse text selection:

[image]

#### Find/Replace... selection:

[image]

#### Looking into and changing these settings did not help:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I once ran into the same problem and used the `gnome-color-chooser` to resolve this issue.

Comment: I tried to search for gnome-color-chooser in the AUR to no avail. Can the goal be achieved by modifying the ~/.gtkrc-2.0 file from the command line? If so, what should I add/change in the ~/.gtkrc-2.0 file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change property **selected_bg_color** value in your current GTK theme gtkrc file. I am using **Ambiance** theme.

So my setting are:

cat /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc | more

> gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#ffffff\nfg_color:#4c4c4c\ntooltip_fg_color:#000000\n**selected_bg_color:#f07746**\nselected_fg_color:#FFFFFF\ntext_color:#3C3C3C\nbg_color:#F2F1F
>   0\ntooltip_bg_color:#f5f5c5\nlink_color:#DD4814"

Also refer these post which helps you in future for similar kinds of problems.

- [Change Eclipse sidebar vertical scope highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151476/change-eclipse-sidebar-vertical-scope-highlighting)
- [eclipse-on-ubuntu-fixing-the-black-background-color-in-hover](http://blog.vogella.com/2012/12/04/eclipse-papercut-10-eclipse-on-ubuntu-fixing-the-black-background-color-in-hover/)

Comment: I tried your solution and it changed the **text selection** colour to `#F07746` (orange) only for Firefox text selection. So it did work, but not for Eclipse.. and yes, I am restarting Eclipse each time I make a change. My `gtkrc` file is located here: `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-2.0/gtkrc`. I changed Manjaro's theme to Oxygen and then Breeze. That did not help either. Now I'm wondering if what I seek is at all feasible.